# Atalho para criar estrutura de um componente React no VSCode

Tags: react

Gostaria de saber se existe algum atalho no VSCode para criar automaticamente a estrutura de um componente tipo:

```js
const { render } = require("react-dom");
import React from 'react';

import Time from './Time';
import Partida from './Partida';

export default class PlacarContainer extends React.Component {
   
    render() {
        return (
            
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Você pode criar seus próprios _snippets_ para fazer isso. Consulte a **[documentação do VSCode](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/userdefinedsnippets#_create-your-own-snippets)** para saber mais.

Comment: Procura pelos snippets da RocketSeat na aba de extensões, já trabalham um tempo com isso e tem bastante coisa pronta.

Answer (score 0):

O VSCode permite que você crie, seus próprios atalhos (scripts) e essa estrutura descrita cabe sim em um snippet que inclusive conter variáveis (como o nome de fuma função, ou os imports, enfim, você quem programa o snippet para preencher ele da maneira que for mais conveniente.
Neste artigo (https://www.brasap.com.br/vs-code-criando-seus-proprios-snippets-de-codigo/) você encontra um tutorial que ensina a desenvolver seus próprios snippets sejam eles para um conjunto de linguagens, para um workspace específico ou para uma linguagem única. Tudo isso é configurado e escrito de maneira simplificada em um arquivo no formato JSON e também existem extensões próprias que implementam snippets e que permitem você criar de maneira ainda mais simples.

Answer (score 0):

Sim, existem várias maneiras de criar automaticamente a estrutura de um componente React no VSCode:

1. Atalhos com extensões:

ES7 React/Redux/GraphQL/TypeScript Snippets:

Instale a extensão no Marketplace do VS Code.
Digite rcc no seu arquivo React e pressione Tab.
Digite o nome do componente e pressione Enter.
Reactjs code snippets:

Instale a extensão no Marketplace do VS Code.
Digite rs no seu arquivo React e pressione Tab.
Escolha o tipo de componente que você deseja criar (classe ou função) e pressione Enter.

2. Snippets personalizados:

Crie um novo arquivo JSON em .vscode/snippets.
Dê um nome ao snippet (por exemplo, react-component).
Insira o seguinte código no arquivo JSON:

```
{
  "prefix": "rcc",
  "body": [
    "import React from 'react';",
    "",
    "export default class ${1:ComponentName} extends React.Component {",
    "  render() {",
    "    return (",
    "      <div>",
    "        // Insira o código do seu componente",
    "      </div>",
    "    );",
    "  }",
    "}",
  ],
  "description": "Cria um componente React com classe"
}
```

Use o código com cuidado.
Salve o arquivo e reinicie o VS Code.
Digite rcc no seu arquivo React e pressione Tab.
Digite o nome do componente e pressione Enter.

3. IntelliSense do VS Code:

Digite import React from 'react'; no seu arquivo React.
Digite class e pressione Enter.
Digite o nome do componente e pressione Enter.
O VS Code criará automaticamente a estrutura básica de um componente React com classe.